# How to stop game, after the player wins in [XO game] with react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I create this game with React.
I want to finish the game after the first player wins an XO game in React.
In other words:
After the first player wins, the next player can not continue the game and the game ends.
this is my code:

```js
function App() {
    const [state,setstate]=useState({
        player: "CIRCLE",
        positions: [
            'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
            'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
            'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
        ]
    })

   
    // mark X or O
    function takeTurn(position) {
        const positions=[...state.positions];
        
        positions[position] = state.player;

        setstate({
            player:state.player === 'CIRCLE' ? 'CROSS' : 'CIRCLE',
            positions,
        })
    }


    return(
        <div >
            <div className="player"> Player :  [{state.player}] </div>
          
            <div  className="total">
                <Square position={0}  value={state.positions[0]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={1}  value={state.positions[1]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={2}  value={state.positions[2]} takeTurn={takeTurn}   />            
                <Square position={3}  value={state.positions[3]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={4}  value={state.positions[4]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={5}  value={state.positions[5]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={6}  value={state.positions[6]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={7}  value={state.positions[7]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  />            
                <Square position={8}  value={state.positions[8]} takeTurn={takeTurn}  /> 
            </div>
            <div className="caption">
                Winner = &nbsp; {winner && <Result winner={winner} />}    
            </div>
            <div className="reset"><button onClick={reset} >Reset</button></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you need a few things.

- A way to determine if there is a winner
- The definition of the `winner` variable

You could add the `winner` to your state, and change the winner calculation line to:

```js
Winner = &nbsp; {state.winner && <Result winner={state.winner} />}
```

To calculate the winner, the app needs to know the winning lines and check if the same symbol is in all 3:

```js
function calculateWinner(positions) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        if (positions[a] && positions[a] === positions[b] && positions[a] === positions[c]) {
            return positions[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can then use this in your `takeTurn` function to `return` early if there is already a winner and therefore not update the board, and also to recalculate if there is a winner each time:

```js
function takeTurn(position) {
    const positions = [...state.positions];
    if (!state.winners) return;

    positions[position] = state.player;

    setstate({
        player: state.player === 'CIRCLE' ? 'CROSS' : 'CIRCLE',
        positions,
        winner: calculateWinner(positions)
    });
}
```

With functional components, it is also a best practice to not have a single `state` object, but to have one for each property you would usually have. This makes it easier to set and manage each on properly, so you may consider changing your state code to:

```js
const [player, setPlayer] = useState('CIRCLE');
const [positions, setPositions = useState([
        'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
        'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
        'EMPTY', 'EMPTY','EMPTY',
      ]);
const [winner, setWinner] = useState(null);
```

and update the setter code accordingly.

Comment: I have a winner but remove it to this codes!